# Which species are Urdhvochhishta, Ardhochhishta and Ubhayochhishta?

Tags: death, garuda-purana

The Dharma Kanda (Preta Kanda) of Garuda Purana contains a great detail on description of hell, the journey of our soul after death. It also contains detailed explanation of cremation rites to be performed for the welfare of the soul. It is in the format of question and answer between Garuda and Lord Krishna. One of the queries raised by Garuda is as follows:

> Garuda said:
>   102. If a man dies out of station and his bones too are destroyed, then how should the rite of cremation be performed. Tell me, O lord of the world!

This query is regarding tragic death caused due to accidents, suicide, due to animals etc., Lord Krishna says there is no other rite besides Narayana Bali which purifies the soul. Lord Krishna answers the query as follows.

> Lord Kṛṣṇa  said
>   104-109. O Garuda, hear. I shall now tell you the great secret about the rite of death for those who die through serpent, tiger, toothed, head.breaking horned animals, disease, stone, water, brāhmaṇa, dog, nails, iron; those who die of hunger, poison, fire and cholera; those who are killed by a bull, a
>   thief, a cāṇdāla, a woman in her menses, Śaunaki, Śūdra, washerman; those who commit suicide or die by fall from a tree, bill, wall or precipice; those who die in water, on cot, in firmament, in bondage; **those who are killed by Ūrdhvocchiṣṭa, Ardhocchiṣṭa or Ubhayocchiṣṭa**; those who die of wounds by
>   weapon on horseback.
>
> [Dharma Kanda chapter 4]

He also mentions those who are killed by Ūrdhvocchiṣṭa, Ardhocchiṣṭa or Ubhayocchiṣṭa (bolded in English translation). Following is Sanskrit verse for the translation in bold.

> **ūrdhvocachiṣṭādharocchiṣṭobhayocchiṣṭāstu ye mṛtāḥ** /
>   śastraghātairmṛtā ye cāsyaśvaspṛṣṭāstathaiva ca // GarP_2,4.109 //

The word Ūrdhva means vertical or higher. Ubhaya means two or bi and Artha means half. From the formation of words, it seems like it is talking about some classification. What is this classification based on? Who/which are these species?

Comment: Translation of that bold line is missing from [IndianScriptures.in](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-1/chapter-01/topic-6)

Answer (score 4):

This question is an excellent reason why one must refer multiple translations when encountering ambiguous verses.

First, most important thing is to look at the original Sanskrit verses

> [गरुडपुराणम् - प्रेतकाण्डः (धर्मकाण्डः) - अध्यायः ४](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_(%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA)
>
> **ऊर्ध्वोचछिष्टाधरोच्छिष्टोभयोच्छिष्टास्तु ये मृताः** ।
> शस्त्रघातैर्मृता ये चास्यश्वस्पृष्टास्तथैव च ॥ १०९ ॥

The question says - *"The word Ūrdhva means vertical or higher. Ubhaya means two or bi and Artha means half."*

#### It's not Ardha (अर्ध), but "Adhara (अधर)".

Now, let's see what meaning we get for these three words, along with the verb - Ucchiṣṭa, from the [Kosha Meta Dictionary collection](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/)

> - 1. [Ūrdhva](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/Urdhva?q=%E0%A4%8A%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5) (ऊर्ध्व) - Upper
> - 2. [Adhar](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/adhara?q=%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%B0) (अधर) = Lower, Lip (lower lip)
> - 3. [Ubhaya](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/ubhaya?q=%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%AF) (उभय) = Both
> - 4. [Ucchiṣṭa](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/ucchiSTa?q=%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9B%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F) (उच्छिष्ट) = [Enjoyed](https://archive.org/details/compendiumofmole00mole/page/59/mode/1up?view=theater), Eaten

#### Therefore, the verse isn't talking about any mono/bipedal/quad legged species of any animal or any being.

#### The words - Ūrdhvocchiṣṭa, Adharocchiṣṭa and Ubhayocchiṣṭa , refers to intimate or sexual dalliance with the aforementioned women.

This proposition becomes crystal clear when we look at the Hindi Translation of this section by the renowned [Gita Press Publication](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaGitaPressGorakhpur/page/n478/mode/1up?view=theater).

> [image]
>
> A menstuating women, a Śūdrāṇī, a Cāṇḍālī, a Washer-women, and the likes. The one who dies while in a dalliance or enjoying (उच्छिष्ट) with the aforementioned (ऊर्ध्व) women by involving either in physical touch or lip kiss (अधर) or both (उभय) - is deemed to have suffered a bad death.

---

### Therefore, those words (viz. Ūrdhvocchiṣṭa, Adharocchiṣṭa or Ubhayocchiṣṭa), are not some classification of a species, but refers to intimate acts like kissing and other sexual acts.